# What does it mean "Formal German representative"?

Tags: meaning

What does it mean
**"Formal German representative" (of whatever company)?** 
If you see this title (in the head of the paper blank), what do you understand?

> 1) It means: representative **in** German
>
> 2) It means: representative **of** German

Comment: I beg you not to ask what anything means "without context". Real language (as opposed to examples in schoolbooks) does not occur outside of contexts, and contexts impose narrow constraints on how we understand words and phrases, and even entire paragraphs. This might mean any number of things. We have no idea what is being *represented* to whom; whether *German* denotes a language or a literature or a nation or some national organization; whether  *formal* modifies *German* or *representative*; or what sort of formality is intended and with what sort of informality it contrasts.

Comment: Thank you I edited it. Let me know what you think of it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to me like an awkward 'dictionary' translation of a title that would probably be represented somewhat differently in English. There are a couple of possibilities.

- *Formal representative* might mean  *official* or *accredited agent of [COMPANY]*, and *formal German representative* would then mean the company's agent in Germany, empowered to act in that country on the company's behalf.
- Many governments require that agents of foreign companies or of companies in certain regulated lines of business file credentials with the authorities, and these are typically called *registered representatives*. A *registered German representative* might be either a representative registered in Germany or a representative of a German company registered elsewhere.